# Perforce Helix4Git Cannot map graph repo in client with no permissions

Tags: perforce

I Installed Helix4Git ti mirror some repos from github and wanted to create client workspace to sync them.
So for started on server I

```
p4 repo //repo/test
```

And to verify

```
p4 repos
//repo/test admin  2020/04/28 14:05:29 Created by admin.
//repo/unreal gconn-user  2020/04/28 13:39:11 Mirror of https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine.git
```

Ok seems my repos are on server.

So back to my local machine

```
p4 client -T graph MyWorkspace
```

Notepad open and so:

```
Client: MyWorkspace

Update: 2020/04/28 13:22:32

Access: 2020/04/28 14:11:05

Owner:  user

Host:   host

Description:
    Created by user.

Root:   i:/graph

Options:    noallwrite noclobber nocompress unlocked nomodtime normdir

SubmitOptions:  submitunchanged

LineEnd:    local

Type:   graph

View:
    //repo/test/... //MyWorkspace/...
```

and:

Error in client specification.
Mapping '//repo/test/...' is not under '//depot/...'.

I'm quite out of ideas. Pretty much followed docs on this one and I can't get it to work for past few hours.

Comment: Does `p4 depots` show that you have a depot called `repo` of type `graph`?

Comment: Hey
P4 depots:



Depot repo 2019/09/07 graph repo/... 'Default graph depot'

Comment: Just to be extra certain, you're running that `p4 depots` on the same local machine where you're running `p4 client -T graph`?  Same connection/credentials?

Comment: Oh no. i run P4 depots directly on remote server, while p4 client -T graph on my local machine.

p4 depots on my local machine does not show  graph depot.

Just to mention P4Admin shows my mirrored unreal repo under Repo/Unreal so I guess it is on the server.

Comment: Your local machine isn't connected to the right server and/or user then.  :)  Check `p4 info` in both places to figure out what the difference in connection settings is.

Comment: Hm there doesn't seem any particular difference beyond what expect (different client names, server names). I'm pretty sure I'm connected to the right server since I've been using it for about a year.


Ok. Giving my user name super access to server, show graph depots on my local machine, which is no particularly perfect solution. Any idea why would it be ?

Comment: Different server names suggests different servers.

Comment: You need to have permission to a depot to be able to sync it -- it doesn't need to be super access, just read access.  It sounds like previously your username had no access at all.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be able to map a depot in your client view, you need at least `list` access to it.  In order to actually sync the files, you need `read` access, and to edit/submit them, you need `write` access.

If you can't see the depots using the `p4 depots` command (using the *same authentication settings* as those you're trying to use to create the client, i.e. the same server, same user, and same client IP), then the depots do not exist from the point of view of either the `p4 depots` or the `p4 client` command.

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 -u bob depots
Depot depot 2019/09/22 local depot/... 'Created by Samwise. '

C:\Perforce\test>p4 -u bob client bobs-client
Error in client specification.
Mapping '//repo/...' is not under '//depot/...'.
Hit return to continue...
Specification not corrected -- giving up.
Edited File C:\Users\Samwise\AppData\Local\Temp\t27688t37.tmp kept due to errors.

C:\Perforce\test>p4 protect -o | tail -n2
        write user bob * //depot/...
```

In this example `bob` does not have access to the `repo` depot, so he can't see it.  If I change his permissions:

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 protect -o | tail -n2
        write user bob * //...


C:\Perforce\test>p4 -u bob depots
Depot Sprocket 2019/07/25 stream 1 Sprocket/... 'Created by Samwise. '
Depot Widget 2019/07/24 stream 1 Widget/... 'Created by Samwise. '
Depot depot 2019/09/22 local depot/... 'Created by Samwise. '
Depot repo 2020/04/28 local repo/... 'Created by Samwise. '
Depot stream 2017/11/02 stream stream/... ''
```

now bob can see all the depots, and he can map any of them in his client.